Equal dot products and cross products.
I'm trying to understand what it means when certain dot products and cross products are equal. So let $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ be nonzero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}=\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c}$, then $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are not necessarily equal. Rather, $\vec{a} \cdot (\vec{b}-\vec{c})=0$, meaning $\vec{a}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{b}-\vec{c}$. Also, the projections of $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ onto $\vec{a}$ are equal (it may also be that $\vec{a}$ is orthogonal to both $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ as well, in which case these projections would be zero).
Next, if $\vec{a}\times \vec{b}=\vec{a} \times \vec{c}$, then all three vectors are coplanar. Specifically, $\vec{a} \times (\vec{b}-\vec{c})=0$, meaning $\vec{a}$ is parallel to $\vec{b}-\vec{c}$. Again, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are not necessarily equal.
Finally, if $\vec{a}\times \vec{b}=\vec{a} \times \vec{c}$ and $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}=\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c}$, then by above, $\vec{a}$ is orthogonal and parallel to $\vec{b}-\vec{c}$. Since $\vec{a} \neq \vec{0}$, we must have $\vec{b}-\vec{c}=\vec{0}$ or $\vec{b}=\vec{c}$.
Is any of this correct? Also, is there a more algebraic way to conclude that $\vec{b}=\vec{c}$ for the third part? More specifically, if $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the angles between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{c}$ respectively, then $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}=\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c} \Rightarrow |\vec{b}|$cos$(\theta)=|\vec{c}|$cos$(\phi)$. Similarly, $\vec{a}\times \vec{b}=\vec{a} \times \vec{c} \Rightarrow |\vec{b}|$sin$(\theta)=|\vec{c}|$sin$(\phi)$. Dividing gives tan$(\theta)=$ tan$(\phi) \Rightarrow \theta=\phi$, but this doesn't really help.

Hint: the best algebraic approaches consider $\vec{x}:=\vec{b}-\vec{c}$. You can use trigonometry or$$(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{x})^2+(\vec{a}\times\vec{x})^2=\vec{a}^2\vec{x}^2,$$where $\vec{v}^2$ means $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}$ for $\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}^3$.
